# Fastest way to get unique values for my dataframe columns as a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best way to turn data like this:

```
| col1 | col2 | ... col400
|  tes | abc  |      max
|  tes | onet |      ups
```

into this:

```
Index | col | unique
  1   | col1| tes
  2   | col2| abc
  3   | col2| onet
  ...    
  639 | col400| max
  649 | col400| ups
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `row` also be included, since otherwise there can only be one `col1`, etc.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean - can you clarify please?

Comment: Well a dataframe has an index (the item on the left). But for one index there can only be *one* row. So that would mean there can only be one `col400`, since you can only map one value (for example `max`) on that value.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'll add the index on the left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will have to add an extra index, since otherwise on every column, you can only add *one* row.

You are probably looking for [**`DataFrame.unstack(..)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['tes', 'abc', 'max'], ['tes', 'onet', 'ups']], columns=["col1", "col2", "col400"])
>>> df
  col1  col2 col400
0  tes   abc    max
1  tes  onet    ups
>>> df.unstack()
col1    0     tes
        1     tes
col2    0     abc
        1    onet
col400  0     max
        1     ups
dtype: object
```

Probably in combination with `.reset_index()` to introduce an index that has a unique id, and two columns: one for the "*original row number*", and one for the "*column name*", like:

```
>>> df.unstack().reset_index()
  level_0  level_1     0
0    col1        0   tes
1    col1        1   tes
2    col2        0   abc
3    col2        1  onet
4  col400        0   max
5  col400        1   ups
```

**or**

```
df = (df.unstack()
      .reset_index(level=0)
      .rename(columns={'level_0':'col',0:'unique'})
      .reset_index(drop=True))

df.index += 1
print(df)

#      col unique
#1    col1    tes
#2    col1    tes
#3    col2    abc
#4    col2   onet
#5  col400    max
#6  col400    ups
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering performance on actual data, you might prefer `melt` over `unstack`. In this example `melt` gives you a 2.5x speedup, and the syntax is simpler.

**Assume we have the following data**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}": range(100_000) for i in range(400)})
df.shape
# (100000, 400)
```

**Performance with `melt`**

```py
%%timeit
df.melt(var_name="col", value_name="unique")
# 857 ms ± 2.97 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Performance with `unstack`**

```py
%%timeit
(
    df.unstack()
    .reset_index(level=0)
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "col", 0: "unique"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
# 2.15 s ± 8.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```